# Highstock error: a.ownerDocument is undefined

Tags: highcharts

I am using the following code in my javascript but getting the error when chart is rendered i.e. "a.ownerdocument is undefined" If I plot the line graphs in "highchart" library then it works fine. here is the exact code from my side.

```
(function ($) {


    $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {
                        // alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");


                        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

                            // split the data set into ohlc and volume
                            var ohlc = [],
                                volume = [],
                                dataLength = data.length,
                                // set the allowed units for data grouping
                                groupingUnits = [[
                                    'week',                         // unit name
                                    [1]                             // allowed multiples
                                ], [
                                    'month',
                                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
                                ]],

                                i = 0;

                            for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
                                ohlc.push([
                                    data[i][0], // the date
                                    data[i][1], // open
                                    data[i][2], // high
                                    data[i][3], // low
                                    data[i][4] // close
                                ]);

                                volume.push([
                                    data[i][0], // the date
                                    data[i][5] // the volume
                                ]);
                            }

                            // create the chart
                            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                                rangeSelector: {
                                    selected: 1
                                },

                                title: {
                                    text: 'AAPL Historical'
                                },

                                yAxis: [{
                                    labels: {
                                        align: 'right',
                                        x: -3
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'OHLC'
                                    },
                                    height: '60%',
                                    lineWidth: 2
                                }, {
                                    labels: {
                                        align: 'right',
                                        x: -3
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: 'Volume'
                                    },
                                    top: '65%',
                                    height: '35%',
                                    offset: 0,
                                    lineWidth: 2
                                }],

                                series: [{
                                    type: 'candlestick',
                                    name: 'AAPL',
                                    data: ohlc,
                                    dataGrouping: {
                                        units: groupingUnits
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    type: 'column',
                                    name: 'Volume',
                                    data: volume,
                                    yAxis: 1,
                                    dataGrouping: {
                                        units: groupingUnits
                                    }
                                }]
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It works fine in Jsfiddle.net however when I use it in Drupal environment then it gives this error. All the charts when used with "highcharts" option works fine however when "highstock" option is used then it gives error.

Comment: So it looks like a conflict with drupal scripts, have you tried to disable all your extensions / plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any other graph library like flot etc or any conflicting library.. Remove them.

Same question answered here: [Initializing Highstock.js throws a jQuery error in getComputedStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333228/initializing-highstock-js-throws-a-jquery-error-in-getcomputedstyle)

Comment: No i am not using any other library.